# How to add onload event handler on dynamically created iframe component in lightning?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, search

I am dynamically creating and adding an iframe like this -

```
$A.createComponent(
      'iframe',
      {
        'aura:id': 'iframe',
        src: iframeUrl,
      },
      function(createdIframe, status) {
         if (status === 'SUCCESS') {
          var body = component.get('v.body');
          body.push(createdIframe);
          component.set('v.body', body);
         }
      }
)
```

The iframe is getting added by this. Now i want to add an `onload` event handler to the iframe to detect when the iframe does not load for the given `iframeUrl`.

I tried these 2 approaches -

1. I added onload to the list of params passed to createComponent -

   ```
   $A.createComponent(
         'iframe',
         {
           'aura:id': 'iframe',
           src: iframeUrl,
           onload: "alert('iframe loaded')"
         },
   ```
2. I added `addEventListener` to the `createdIframe`.

   ```
   createdIframe.addEventHandler('load', function() {
               alert('iframe loaded');
             });
   ```

But in both cases, the alert wasn't called. Not sure what I am missing here.
Can you please help me with finding out when is the iframe onload called.

Comment: did you try  `onLoad:component.getReference('c.handleiframeonload');` then you can create new function with name `handleiframeonload : function(cmp,evt,hel){}`

Comment: @sdandamud1 worked with `onload:component.getReference('c.handleiframeonload');`  Please add as an answer so i can accept and close. Thanks!

Comment: added as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should bind event dynamically with [`component.getreference`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_handler.htm). and can reference another function in the controller. your code should be

```
$A.createComponent(
  'iframe',
  {
    'aura:id': 'iframe',
    src: iframeUrl,
    onload:component.getReference('c.handleiframeonload');
  },);

handleiframeonload : function(cmp,evt,hel){
// write your onload logic here.
}
```